# Not able to update the comment module on the mvc view using ajax call without refreshing the page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, entity-framework-4

This is a check & mate situation for me...
I am using mvc 3.
I am trying to make a post and comment module on a single view. below is the code for the view and controller. I am able to get the post and all the comments on load but once I add a new comment through an AJAX call its is saved to the correct table in DB but I am not understanding how to update it on view without refreshing the page...

```
//model
public class PostViewModel
{
   public bool? IsActive
    { get; set; }

   public string PostDescription
    { get; set; }

   ...

    public List<PostCommentModel> objPostCommentInfo { get; set; }
}

//Post Controller

 DBEntities1 db = new DBEntities1();

    public ActionResult Index(int ID)
    {

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
        PostViewModel objPostViewModel = new PostViewModel();
        List<PostViewModel> lstobjPostViewModel = new List<PostViewModel>();

        PostCommentModel objPostCommentModel;
        List<PostCommentModel> lstobjPostCommentModel = new List<PostCommentModel>();

        var objPost = (from x in db.PostInfoes 
                        where x.PostId  == id
                        select x).ToList();

        var objPostComment = (from y in db.PostCommentInfoes  
                               where y.PostId  == id
                               orderby y.CommentId  descending
                               select y).ToList();

        foreach  (var x in objPost)
        {

            objPostViewModel.PostID = x.PostId;
            objPostViewModel.IsActive = x.IsActive;
            objPostViewModel.PostTitle = x.PostTitle;
            objPostViewModel.PostDescription = x.PostDescription;
            lstobjPostViewModel.Add(objPostViewModel);
        }

        foreach (var y in objPostComment)
        {
            objPostCommentModel = new PostCommentModel();
            objPostCommentModel.PostId  = y.PostId;
            objPostCommentModel.IsActive  = y.IsActive;
            objPostCommentModel.CommentBody = y.CommentBody;
            lstobjPostCommentModel.Add(objPostCommentModel);
        }
        objPostViewModel.objPostCommentInfo = lstobjPostCommentModel;
        return View(lstobjPostViewModel);
    }

  //view
  @model IEnumerable<MVCProjectModels.PostViewModel>

<table border="1">
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <text>Created By:</text>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostDescription)
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostDescription)
        </td>
    </tr>
    .....
  }
 </table>
 <table>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <textarea cols="10" rows="5" id="txtComment"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input id="btnPostComment" type="button" value="Post Comment" />
    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <table border="1">
 @foreach (var item1 in Model)
 {
    foreach (var item2 in item1.objPostCommentInfo)
    {    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.CommentBody)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
  }
 </table>
```

//Ajax call to update the comment (The comments gets saves to the database but I am not finding anyway to update it on the UI or View)

```
       <script type="text/javascript">

       $("#btnPostComment").click(function () {
       var commentBody = $("#txtComment").val();
       postComment(commentBody);
       });
       function postComment(commentBody) {
       $.ajax({
       url: "/Post/postComment", // this controller method calls a store procedure to insert the new comment in the database.
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
              Comment: commentBody,
              ID: 6
          },
          success: function (result) {

          },
          error: function () {
              alert("error");
          }
        });
        }
        </script>
```

Please let me know if I am doing any major designing mistakes in the above module. I am new to mvc so just trying to do this by reading some books and articles so not sure if this is correct way of achieving such results. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name your table for easier reference:

```
<table border="1" id="postList">
```

On your view you are writing a name of a user `<text>Created By:</text>` but I don't see that in the model. So assuming that is saved in a session or you can retrieve it in your controller you can do something like:

```
public ActionResult PostComment(YourModel input){
    // everything went well
    // you get this from a session or from the database
    var username = "the creator";
    return Json(new { success = true, username});
}
```

On `success` of your ajax call:

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result.success) {
        $("#postList").append('<tr><td><text>Created By:</text>' +
            result.username + '</td><td rowspan="2">' +
            commentBody + '</td>');
    </tr>
    }
}
```

It will be cool though if instead of concatenating the `tr` string that you read it from a `template` and insert the necessary values. Or you can use other tools like knockout to do the binding on the client side. But that is for another question I guess.

Comment: yes ..i am sorry I am setting many values in the model... just deleted them to reduce the question size..but yes I am getting the created by value correctly from db..I am not setting it in cookie...there are no errors in this module ..but I am not finding the way to display comments that are stored to database through AJAX call ..if I refresh the page every thing is fine..

Comment: Okay, then my suggested code fits your scenario. Have you tried it and is there an additional question?

Comment: Yes I am understanding your code ....but what will happen if I hit refresh.. will there be 2 same comments ???Because I am getting the comments on post controllers Index actionresult()..

Comment: No there won't be because your view will be refreshed entirely, when you call the method that renders the view in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You could just [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) the new comment text to the comments table in the success callback of your AJAX call:

```
success: function (result) {
    // give your comments table a class="comments" so that the following
    // selector is able to match it:
    $('table.comments').prepend(
        $('<tr/>', {
            html: $('<td/>', {
                text: commentBody
            })
        })    
    );
}
```

Comment: if I do this ... after the page postback's later, will there be 2 same comments ...because onpage load I am binding all the comments from the DB ..

Comment: OnPageLoad is called only once, when the DOM is loaded initially.